# android button onClick not transitioning to new activity

Tags: android, onclick, buttonclick

So I am very new to Android development and this may be a simple question where I am missing a simple thing. I have a class where I have a button and I am trying to click a button and transition to another activity.

```
public class ContentProfile extends AppCompatActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_profile);

    }

    public void settingsPage(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ContentProfile.this, ContentSettings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

I am trying to open up the ContentSetting class. The XML for ContentProfile is:

```
    <Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:onClick="settingsPage"/>
```

And the Content settings looks like:

```
public class ContentSettings extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_settings);

    }


}
```

I am trying to go from a button in ContentProfile to ContentSettings. I have read the documentation for this [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). I have trying going off of this documentation but I cannot seem to figure it out. Should I be looking at another document to figure this out? Am I overlooking something simple?

EDIT: here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.speed_read">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ContentProfile"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.user.speed_read.ContentSettings" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ContentSettings"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass another activity when click the button, you can use button click listener. easy way to do it. if you do this way, you can delete onclick from your xml.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(ContentProfile.this, ContentSettings.class);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
     });
```

Comment: I've tried this solution and still nothing happens when I click the button. Really baffled.

Answer (score 0):

1. Where is your onClickListener method in the Content profile class? Your onClickListener method must have the settingsPage method inside it.  Example:

`final Button settingsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);`

```
View.OnClickListener goToSettings = new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
            openSettings();
       }
};
```

`settingsButton.setOnClickListener(goToSettings);`

2. You must specify the ContentSettings activity in AndroidManifest.xml
3. ContentSettings activity must set the correct content name for the XML layout. Is activity_content_settings the exact name of your XML layout?

Comment: what is openSettings() doing? is that just my settingsPage() method? Not sure how you are breaking all of this up. Is the View.OnClickListener go in the onCreate?

Comment: also points 2 and 3 are both yes. its in the AndroidManifest and exact same XML

Comment: openSettings is just your settingsPage method, yes.  That is just the name I called the settings page method in one of my own apps.  But it is the same thing.

Comment: Also the Button declation, the View.OnClickListener, and settingsButton.setOnClickListener(goToSettings) ALL go inside onCreate method